# C++ get appdata path of other users

Tags: c++, windows

In my program I have been using `SHGetFolderPath` to get the AppData path. However I need to get the AppData path of the other users on the computer. The only way I can think to do it is to get the path for the current user, and then replace the current user's name with the other users names. I don't know how to get a list of the users. There's probably a much more elegant solution aswell... If you have insight I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you need that? You don't have access to those folders, unless you're running with full privileges (and you need to have a good excuse for that).

Comment: I can't think of a good reason for doing this.  It doesn't sound very robust.

Comment: In previous versions of my program I had the config file in the appdata. I'm moving it into Program Files in the newest version so all the users can share the saves. If possible (if the current user) has the rights, I would like to do that for all the users.

Comment: @Lienau: Program Files is a read-only location, you can't move any writeable data to it.

Comment: The answer might not exist yet (!) In corporate environments, this is quite common. Even if it did exist, it might not be useful: what would you do if your AppData is "H:\AppData", and theirs is _also_ "H:\AppData", but they'd happen to be different "H:\" shares ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your situation I would recommend the following:

1. Continue to store configuration files in AppData, but store it in CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA (SHGetFolderPath).  This AppData is shared with all users.  Your setup program (or an administrator user) can set up a folder in this location named after your program that gives "Everyone" full access (this is very easy with Windows Installer).  That way, any user can read/write to it.  Everything in "Program Files" should never change.  It should only contain read-only executables, DLLs, and other such resources.  Microsoft has long discouraged writing to this location and many administrators no longer expect to encounter custom user data that requires regular backup & restore in Program Files.
2. When your software runs, you can check for data in the current user's AppData (i.e. stored by your old version) and merge it with the data in the machine's AppData (described by #1 above).  To migrate the data for the user, log in as that user and run your software.

There really isn't a great way that I'm aware of for gathering all that data from other user profiles.  Nothing supported by Microsoft, that is (that I'm aware of!).

Regarding storage of data in Program Files:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776776(VS.85).aspx "Do not store user data under the Program Files folder."  There are many other references that say similar.